# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for format yyMMdd

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string like below :

```
"9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM"
```

Would love to convert it to format `yyMMdd`

```
 var evan = dataRow["ValueDate"].ToString(); //Output is "9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM"  
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(evan,"yyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Than to diplay :

```
dt.ToString("yyMMdd");
```

> Error Message :  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for
>   format yyMMdd

What is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` is expecting the data you give it to be in the EXACT format you specify. Your string `9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM` does not match your format `yyMMdd`

Comment: Have a look at [custom-date-and-time-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParseExact` is for parsing a string that's being input in a specific format. To display the string, you pass the format string to the `ToString` method:

```
var evan = dataRow["ValueDate"].ToString("yyMMdd");
```

Comment: Thank you , Yes but I need to convert it to  format  `yyMMdd` not just simply display it

Comment: @napi15 what do you mean by "convert it"?

Comment: A `DateTime` is a `DateTime`. There is no "conversion". The format that you're referring to is only used for display purposes.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand , thanks a lot for clarification

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact` is expecting the data you give it to be in the EXACT format you specify. Your string `9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM` does not match your format `yyMMdd`. So either try using just `DateTime.Parse`, or make your format match the data. Something like

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(evan,"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
```

Then you should be able to do `dt.ToString("yyMMdd");`

Comment: Very helpful thank you , I used your intel to fix my problem . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After gathering intel from posters I succed in understanding and solving my mistake :

After carefully consulting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx) this is the solution I was looking for :

**Input** :

```
dataRow["ValueDate"].ToString() //  "9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM"
```

**Code :**

```
 DateTime convertedDate;
 convertedDate=Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow["ValueDate"].ToString());
 var evan = convertedDate.ToString("yyMMdd");
```

**Output :**

```
"170930" //just like I need
```

Like Michael sharp explained earlier :

`DateTime.ParseExact` is expecting the data you give it to be in the EXACT format you specify. My string `9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM` did not match my format `yyMMdd`